# window_open() has stopped working, how do I find out why?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

For a long time my page (built round a Leaflet map) has had a button which triggers a dropdown of buttons, each of which opens a specific URL in a new browser tab.
In Chrome on Android those tabs are collected in a single tab group, which is all that's required, so the code is very minimalist.

This has worked for months without fuss. However it has now stopped, no windows or tabs are opened.
The console.log statements in the code below show that everything is functional except the actual window.open()) instruction.

Recently I've been concentrating on a completely separate part of the map (gpx track layers) which to my mind has no bearing on HTML or browser behaviour.
However it's entirely possible I've introduced something that interferes, but I have no idea what to look for nor what diagnostics to use.

None of the original code shown has changed for a long time, though for this post I have included direct links and (better) tester code found at https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+window.open+blank, which is based on the best practice example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

html

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="do_dropdown()" class="dropbtn">New Tabs</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <br><button class='button' id="click_btn" onclick="  getgurl()">Google</button>

        <!-- links -->
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">link to Google</a>
        <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/" target="_blank">link to Firefox</a>

        <!-- tester -->
        <p>
            <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/"
                target="PromoteFirefoxWindow"
                onclick="openRequestedPopup(this.href, this.target); return false;"
                title="This link will create a new window or will re-use an already opened one">
            Promote Firefox adoption</a>
        </p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#click_btn {
    height: 30px; 
    width: 150px; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #73AD21;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: blue;
    margin: 5px;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #bedef4;
    color: blue;
    padding: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

javascript

```
<script>

    // original; has worked, now doesn't open anything
    function getgurl() {
        const gurl = "https://www.google.com/";
        console.log('gurl', gurl)
        window.open(gurl);
    }

    // tester
    var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable;
    function openRequestedPopup(url, windowName) {
    
        console.log('windowName  ' , windowName , ' url  ', url)
        
        if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed) {
            windowObjectReference = window.open(url, windowName, "resizable,scrollbars,status");
            console.log('windowObjectReference  ' , windowObjectReference);
        } else {
            windowObjectReference.focus();
        };
    }    
</script>
```

The links work properly, the original button and tester function do not open anything.
Checked with Windows Firefox & Chrome, Linux Firefox on a different PC, and Android Chrome.

There's one further peculiarity I've never noticed before and don't understand.
If the URL for the button is of the form "https://www.example.co.uk/some_page.html"
the console logging shows "https://www.example.co.uk/some_page.htmL" with the final letter capitalised.
Replacing the 'l' with an 'x' does not capitalise. Using .toLowerCase() has no effect. It does not open a .htmL file if one exists.

Comment: Have you used incognito mode and see if it is an extension that is blocking it?

Comment: Nothing in that code is going to change a string so unclear how it would happen.

Comment: If I was you, I'd simply change `window.open` with `location.href`

Comment: Incognito mode makes no difference.

Comment: Using location.href = some_gurl does indeed open a Google page, which may resolve the immediate issue, thankyou.  However the question remains open,.